# Can a module know name of host file?

Tags: python

Say I have  a `script.py` that imports  `module.py`,

In the module, `__file__` returns `path\module.py`

Is there a variable or something I can use in the module that returns `path\script.py` or `script.py`?

at the moment I'm doing `module.config(__file__)` in script.py instead.

Comment: You can likely use `inspect` but I don't like to rely on it

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using a method and passing a variable you have, but what is the use case for having something know what other modules have imported it?

Comment: I actually think your approach is the best. A lower layer in a design (i.e. an imported module) ought to have no interaction with a higher layer than what the higher layer proactively does with it. If `module.py` needs a piece of information (such as the file name `"script.py"`), it is up to the user (`script.py`) to provide it

Comment: @SuperStormer ```import __main__``` and then ```logfile=open("{f}.log".format(f=__main__.__file__),"a")``` works great

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm making a simple logger that writes the log filename based on the name of the  host file.

Comment: The builtin logging module should be used for this, rather than using open method